# CodeChef's Tree MEX (Minimum Excludant) challenge

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, time-limit-exceeded, graph

This code is a solution for [CodeChef's Tree MEX problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/TREEMX):

> Minimum excludant (or MEX for short) of a collection of integers is
>   the smallest non-negative integer not present in the set.
>
> You have a tree \$ T \$ with \$n\$ vertices. Consider an ordering \$ P=(v_1,\ldots,v_n) \$
>   of vertices of \$T\$. We construct a sequence \$A(P)=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\$ using the
>   following process:
>
> - Set all \$a_i=−1\$.
> - Process vertices in order \$v_1,\ldots,v_n\$. For the current vertex \$v_i \$ set  \$a_i=\operatorname{MEX}(a_{u_1},\ldots,a_{u_k})\$, where \$u_1,\ldots,u_k\$ is the set of neighbours of
>     \$v_i\$.
>
> For instance, let  \$n=3\$ and \$T\$ be the tree with edges \$(1,2)\$ and
>   \$(2,3)\$. Then,  for the ordering \$P=(1,2,3)\$ we obtain the sequence
>   \$A(P)=(0,1,0)\$, while    for the ordering \$P=(2,3,1)\$ we obtain
>   \$A(P)=(1,0,1)\$.
>
> Consider all \$n!\$ orders \$P\$. How many different sequences
>   \$A(P)\$ can we obtain? Print the answer modulo \$10^9+7\$.

---

I have created a graph from list of tuples and then calculated `mex` values for each permutation.

```
Ex: 3    # 3 vertices
    1 2  # (1,2) edge
    2 3  # (2,3) edge
```

permutations(1,2,3) ==> we get 6 combinations

For 6 combinations we will get 6 values. I need to print distinct count of that 6 values.

**Code:**

```
# https://www.codechef.com/problems/TREEMX


from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import permutations


class Graph:
    """ Graph is data structure(directed). """


    def __init__(self, connections):
        """ Initializing graph with set as default value. """
        self._graph = defaultdict(set)
        self.add_connections(connections)

    def add_connections(self, connections):
        """ Add connections(list of tupules) to graph. """
        for node1, node2 in connections:
            self.add(node1,node2)

    def add(self, node1, node2):
        """ Add node1 and node2 to graph which is initialized with set by default. """
        self._graph[node1].add(node2)
        self._graph[node2].add(node1)

    def get_graph(self):
        return dict(self._graph)


def mex(arr_set):
    mex = 0
    while mex in arr_set:
        mex+=1
    return mex


def process(graph, order):
    a_p = [-1] * len(order)
    for el in order:
        a_p[el-1] = mex([a_p[u-1] for u in graph[el]])
    return a_p

t = int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    v = int(input())
    e = []
    for i in range(v-1):
        e.append(tuple(map(int, input().split())))

    g = Graph(e)
    all_vertices = {s for i in e for s in i}
    result = []
    for p in permutations(all_vertices, v):
        out = process(g.get_graph(), p)
        result.append(out) if out not in result else None

    print(len(result) % ((10**9)+7))
```

**Constraints:**

- \$1≤T≤10\$
- \$1≤n≤10^5\$
- \$1≤u_i,v_i≤n\$
- \$u_i≠v_i\$

How can I optimize the code, to get rid of the "time limit exceeded" error?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>     for p in permutations(all_vertices, v):
> ```

> - \$1≤n≤10^5\$

Well, \$(10^5)! \approx \left(\frac{10^5}{e}\right)^{10^5} \approx 10^{35657}\$ so it's a waste of time trying to optimise this. The only thing to do is go back to the drawing board and spend a few hours thinking about the mathematics. At best the code you've written will serve to analyse all trees up to a small number of vertices (maybe 7 or 8) to see what patterns you can spot which can help to guide you in the right direction.